# PHP store hours night

Tags: php, date, time

So I'm trying to create an open and close message with PHP for a webshop where visitors can order.

The storehours are currently stored in this format:

```
1 12:00-22:00
2 12:00-23:00
3 closed-closed
4 12:00-02:50
5 12:00-23:00
etc..
```

So for the first 3 days. it's pretty easy to print a closed message as you just compare the strings with date("Hi") and check if the current time is between de store hours. But when it comes to the 4th day, with overnight hours I get to struggle.  As the time hits 00:00 it checks, of course, the closing date of day 5, while actually, it should check if it is open at night.

Is there a reliable way of getting this to work?

Comment: You could split the fourth day into two parts so it's: 4th day 12:00-23:59, 5th day 00:00-02:50 and 12:00-23:00.

Comment: This may be easier to handle using the DateTime class, as it has some built in span-checks (http://php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php)

Comment: In the simplest of terms, you need to check both date and time for pairs that roll-over into the next day. What's the code for actually doing the check look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can work.
I convert the open and close times to a unix value.

If close is before open I add one day in seconds.

Now I have a unix value of when it opens and when it closes today and all I need to do is to compare against time().

```
$otime="16:15";
$ctime="00:50";
$open = strtotime(date("Y-m-d ").$otime);
$close = strtotime(date("Y-m-d ").$ctime);

If($close<$open) $close += 3600*24;

If(time() >= $open && time() < $close){
    Echo "open";
}Else{
    Echo "closed";
}
```

https://3v4l.org/iqSYH

Answer (score 2):

I didn't account for your `closed-closed` scenario but thats a simple check.

```
$open_close = explode('-', $hours);

// current date and time
$now = new DateTime();

// clone the current datetime and explicity set the time to the open time
$open = clone $now;
$open_time = explode(':', $open_close[0]);
call_user_func_array([$open, 'setTime'], $open_time);

// do the same for the close time
$close_time = explode(':', $open_close[1]);
$close = clone $now;
call_user_func_array([$close, 'setTime'], $close_time);

// if close is greater than close, the close must be the next day unless its a data entry error, but we cant really prevent that, so assume its good and modify the date time for close to be the next day
if ($open > $close) {
   $close->modify('+1 day');
}

// now a basic comparison to see if $now is between $open and $close
if ($now < $close && $now >= $open) {
  echo 'OPEN';
} else {
  echo 'Closed';
}
```

I also didn't address your need to map the days of week to the current day, i assume you have already managed that. If not then you will need to do some tweaking i think, but this should overall get you an accurate comparison.

Comment: `call_user_func_array`? Just use argument unpacking.. `$open->setTime(...$open_time)`

Comment: So I tried your code with input:  $hours = "16:15-00:50". While it should say "OPEN" it says closed. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4ae07a07c07f4bfa3b252b38d3c801825a120084

Comment: @TTS the sandbox have the us pacific timezone and there is currently `14:22`

Comment: @prodigitalson it should be `$now < $close`

Comment: @Philipp even setting the correct timezone is not working -  $now->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Amsterdam'));

Comment: @Philipp, what can i say... its been a minute since ive touched PHP.

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cb86c249e90da60775f79a3bd656fc0ffdcfae2b

Comment: I see Philipp, that seems to be working to. Should I consider this code or is the simple example of andreas

Comment: @TTS both codes are similar in function, but some believe strtotime will stop working in 20 years. I'm not so sure about it. I think some version of PHP will fix the 32 bit issue. But that is the main thing between the codes. Datetime does not have the 32 bit problem. Feel free to choose this if you want.